# Criar objeto javascript com outros objetos

Tags: javascript, react, react-select

Preciso pegar os objetos de arrays javascripts que recebo do backend e transfoma-los em outros objetos para conseguir usar na biblioteca React-select.

Meu objeto vem do backend assim:

```js
[
  { nome: 'Fulano', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1  },
  { nome: 'Ciclano', setor: 'Administrativo', filial: 2  },
  { nome: 'Maria', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1  }
]
```

Para funcionar no React-Select, ele deve ficar assim:

```js
[
  { values: { nome: 'Fulano', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1 }, label: 'Fulano'},
  { values: { nome: 'Ciclano', setor: 'Administrativo', filial: 2 }, label: 'Ciclano'},
  { values: { nome: 'Maria', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1 }, label: 'Maria'}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode transformar uma estrutura na outra:

```js
const original = [
  { nome: 'Fulano', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1  },
  { nome: 'Ciclano', setor: 'Administrativo', filial: 2  },
  { nome: 'Maria', setor: 'Produção', filial: 1  }
]

const adaptado = original.map(usuario => ({
  values: usuario,
  label: usuario.nome
}))

console.log(adaptado)
```

Além disso, você pode usar o hook [useMemo](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) para "memoizar" esse resultado.